# How to create loading spinner with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I create i simple spinner using react js?

Let say that I have code like this :

```
 let cars = [
      {id: 1, name: "Golf"},
      {id: 2, name: "Audi"},
      {id: 3, name: "Passat"},
      {id: 4, name: "Bmw"}
    ];

class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

      this.state = {
        loading: true
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({loading: false})
    }

        render(){
        let content = this.state.loading ? <div>Loading</div> : cars.map((c, i) => <div key={i}>{c.name}</div>)

        return (
        <div>{content}</div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And I'm trying to show `loading` while the list of cars isn't loaded.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1388/)

Any idea?

Comment: Put in a spinner image instead of the text "loading"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to simulate async request

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.setState({loading: false})
    },2000)
} // simulate loading
```

Worked
 [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1391/)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Reactjs is all about a concept called components. So what is a React component?

A React component is a function or a class.

The purpose of a component which is a class or a function is to produce html that we are going to show to the user. Its secondary purpose is to handle feedback from the user. For example, anytime a user clicks or drags or types input, any of those types of events.

Anytime we have content that we need to show the user, we are going to write some amount of jsx. JSX is that code that kind of looks like html. In order to handle feedback from the users, we are going to use these software routines called event handlers.

So when you are looking to add a spinner to your Reactjs application, what do you do? You create a spinner component and you can do so by creating a file called `Spinner.js` and the code inside would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Spinner = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui active dimmer">
      <div className="ui big text loader">Loading...</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spinner;
```

In the above example I am using some classNames taken from Semantic-UI, feel free to check out their documentation. You can then add this `Spinner` component as a component instance to your `Test` component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

  this.state = {
    loading: true
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading: false})
}

    render(){
    let content = this.state.loading ? <Spinner /> : cars.map((c, i) => <div key={i}>{c.name}</div>)

    return (
    <div>{content}</div>
  )
}
```

}

And that is how you create a simple spinner in Reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

with very short code I could generate wait spinner in react component

```
getSpinner:function(){
 return ( this.state.loadingTree?
    <div><img style={{width: '90px', objectFit: 'scale-down', 
     position:'absolute',opacity:'0.95', align: 'middle' }} src= 
    {"/images/spinner.gif"}/></div>:""
 );
},

render(){
   return(){
    <div style={{position:'absolute', top:'40%',left:'50%'}}>{this.getSpinner()} 
   </div>};   }
```